# Where can I find statistical data about legal lawsuits against commercial and investment banks?

Tags: market-data, statistical-finance

I am searching international statistical data about legal lawsuits against banks over allegations on on money laundering, tax fraud, suspicious transaction, financial markets prices manipulation, Illicit financial flows (illegal capital flight) and so on.

Does this information exist in the form appropriate for econometric analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw these:
http://www.cnbc.com/2015/04/30/7-years-on-from-crisis-150-billion-in-bank-fines-and-penalties.html
http://blogs.ft.com/ftdata/2015/07/22/bank-fines-data/
The second permits download data collected by the FT (csv format).
The first aparently use that data and process in Tableau graphics.
I also saw this:
graphics.wsj.com/bank-fines-where-did-the-money-go/#firstPage
May be you can start with it.